# HTML 5 Video has lines at top and bottom border and cannot find way to remove

Tags: css, html, class, video

I am using a straight-forward HTML 5 video set up. The CSS and HTML are minimal. The video plays just fine, the splash image and everything is working great, controls show up. The problem is a dark line shows top and bottom. If I change the HTML divs to reference an "ID" rather than a "Class", the dark lines go away, but I need to use a class because I use a javascript to make sure each video starts at the beginning frame if the filmmakers forget to create a splash image for me. Have tried changing background to transparent, changing borders to 0, I've tried resizing images, and nothing changes.[image: Example Image] I would appreciate any thoughts/guidance you might have. I want to understand what is happening so if you can even just point me in the right direction, I'll dig more.

This is the CSS

```
.video-player {
background-color:#999999;
display: inline-block;
}

.video-player img {
background-color:#000000;

}

.video-tree {
width: 430px;
height: 250px;
}

video {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="video-player">
<div class="video-tree">
<video id="myVideo1" poster="someimage.png" width="430" height="250" controls>
<source src="someVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
</div> <!-- end video-tree class -->
</div><!-- end video-player class -->
```

Comment: If you reference the ID and the line goes away, that means the problem is the class. Why do you need both the video and the class to specify the width and height(use px too)? And last, if using chrome, press F12 for the developer tools, then select the square with the cursor, and lastly click on your video, this will show you the properties for the div/video and what is causing the lines.

Comment: Good question on the size! I'll see if I can tweak that to make a difference. I did use Chrome and IE Developer tools before asking my question and it did not reveal anything that helped. I tried different fixes to the CSS at all levels of the cascade and the HTML, and that's how I came upon the behavior with the ID vs Class. I finally had to admit defeat and reach out for more wisdom. I'll try the change to the multiple sizing and see if that will work and report back. Thank you!